# Only "alt" of image is show in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, image, create-react-app

I have a small React project. Where I call a property from the InfoSection.elements.js , unfortunately only the alt section is displayed in the browser but not the image itself. Please help me showing images. My code is below. Thank you very much .

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import GlobalStyle from "./globalStyles";
import Home from "./pages/HomePage/Home";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Navbar } from "./components";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Data.js :

```
export const homeObjOne = {
  primary: true,
  lightBg: false,
  lightTopLine: true,
  lightText: true,
  lightTextDesc: true,
  topLine: "Marketing Agency",
  headline: "Lead Generation Specialist for Online Businesses",
  description:
    "We help business owners increase their revenue. Our team of unique specialist can help you achieve your business goals.",
  buttonLabel: "Get Started",
  imgStart: "",
  img: require("../../images/svg-1.svg"),
  alt: "Credit Card",
  start: "",
};

export const homeObjTwo = {
  primary: true,
  lightBg: false,
  lightTopLine: true,
  lightText: true,
  lightTextDesc: true,
  topLine: "Instant Setup",
  headline: "Extremely quick onboarding process",
  description:
    "Once you've joined, our team of specialist will reach out to you and get you set up in minutes.",
  buttonLabel: "Learn More",
  imgStart: "",
  img: require("../../images/svg-2.svg"),
  alt: "Vault",
  start: "",
};

export const homeObjThree = {
  primary: false,
  lightBg: true,
  lightTopLine: false,
  lightText: false,
  lightTextDesc: false,
  topLine: "Sarah Jeni",
  headline:
    "Ultra helped me increase my revenue by over 3X in less than 3 months!",
  description:
    "Their team is wonderful! I can't believe I didn't start working with them earlier.",
  buttonLabel: "View Case Study",
  imgStart: "start",
  img: require("../../images/profile.jpg"),
  alt: "Vault",
  start: "true",
};

export const homeObjFour = {
  primary: true,
  lightBg: false,
  lightTopLine: true,
  lightText: true,
  lightTextDesc: true,
  topLine: "Secure Database",
  headline: "All your data is stored on our secure server",
  description:
    "You will never have to worry about your information getting leaked. Our team of security experts will ensure your records are kept safe.",
  buttonLabel: "Sign Up Now",
  imgStart: "start",
  img: require("../../images/profile.jpg"),
  alt: "Vault",
  start: "true",
};
```

Home.js :

```
import React from "react";
import { homeObjOne, homeObjTwo, homeObjThree, homeObjFour } from "./Data";
import { InfoSection } from "../../components";

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <InfoSection {...homeObjOne} />
      <InfoSection {...homeObjThree} />
      <InfoSection {...homeObjTwo} />
      <InfoSection {...homeObjFour} />
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

InfoSection.js :

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Button } from "../../globalStyles";
import {
  InfoSec,
  InfoRow,
  InfoColumn,
  TextWrapper,
  TopLine,
  Heading,
  Subtitle,
  ImgWrapper,
  Img,
} from "./InfoSection.elements";

function InfoSection({
  primary,
  lightBg,
  topLine,
  lightTopLine,
  lightText,
  lightTextDesc,
  headline,
  description,
  buttonLabel,
  img,
  alt,
  imgStart,
  start,
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <InfoSec lightBg={lightBg}>
        <Container>
          <InfoRow imgStart={imgStart}>
            <InfoColumn>
              <TextWrapper>
                <TopLine lightTopLine={lightTopLine}>{topLine}</TopLine>
                <Heading lightText={lightText}>{headline}</Heading>
                <Subtitle lightTextDesc={lightTextDesc}>{description}</Subtitle>
                <Link to="/sign-up">
                  <Button big fontBig primary={primary}>
                    {buttonLabel}
                  </Button>
                </Link>
              </TextWrapper>
            </InfoColumn>
            <InfoColumn>
              <ImgWrapper start={start}>
                <Img src={img} alt={alt} />
              </ImgWrapper>
            </InfoColumn>
          </InfoRow>
        </Container>
      </InfoSec>
    </>
  );
}

export default InfoSection;
```

InfoSection.elements.js :

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const InfoSec = styled.div`
  color: #fff;
  padding: 160px 0;
  background: ${({ lightBg }) => (lightBg ? "#fff" : "#101522")};
`;

export const InfoRow = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 -15px -15px -15px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: ${({ imgStart }) => (imgStart ? "row-reverse" : "row")};
`;

export const InfoColumn = styled.div`
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 50%;
  flex-basis: 50%;

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    max-width: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
`;

export const TextWrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: 540px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 60px;

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    padding-bottom: 65px;
  }
`;

export const ImgWrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: 555px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: ${({ start }) => (start ? "flex-start" : "flex-end")};
`;

export const TopLine = styled.div`
  color: ${({ lightTopLine }) => (lightTopLine ? "#a9b3c1" : "#4B59F7")};
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1.4px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
`;

export const Img = styled.img`
  padding-right: 0;
  border: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 500px;
`;

export const Heading = styled.h1`
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: ${({ lightText }) => (lightText ? "#f7f8fa" : "#1c2237")};
`;

export const Subtitle = styled.p`
  max-width: 440px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: ${({ lightTextDesc }) => (lightTextDesc ? "#a9b3c1" : "#1c2237")};
`;
```

Comment: Providing code to reproduce is good but the code should be "viable" and "minimum" meaning it should produce the problem (so others can investigate) but not have anything that is not needed to reproduce (so other do not waste their time interpreting irrelevant detail), e.g. a single object in Data.js would do and you can probably strip out a lot of properties there and from styles and elements from the markup, e.g. just have `<Img>` as opposed to full `<InfoSec>`. That would also help you investigate, rule out irrelevant influence.

Comment: There are many ways the image may be unavailable to be served. The file can actually be missing or be corrupt, the server may not have read access, the server may prevent pathes like `../../`. What have you ruled out? Have you found any way to display an image, e.g. moving the file to and sourcing it from `images/svg-1.svg`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use create-react-app as boilerplate. If so:

1. Put the images into the public/ folder and there into sth. like assets/images/
2. Then you can change `img: require("../../images/svg-2.svg"),`  to
   `img: "assets/images/svg-2.svg" in Data.js,` and it should work.

I would avoid `require()` if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You must set images address from root like this

require("~/images/profile.jpg")

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/